# Creating shapes with flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to accomplish this arch in my app.
[White arch in flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXzQi.jpg)

[image]

below the white area is a listview. i have it in a Sliver so that when i scroll up, the white part replaces the image so that the listview takes full screen. I just need to find away the make this white arch.

Comment: see `ClipPath` documentation

Comment: Take a look at this post by Liro : https://iirokrankka.com/2017/09/04/clipping-widgets-with-bezier-curves-in-flutter/

Comment: @diegoveloper yea thats the one i found from looking up ClipPath as suggested by pskink, im still learning how to implement it in my situation.